# Is it possible to change war goal?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I had CB to claim two provinces, one through a fabricated claim, and one through mission. I chose to go to war with the mission CB.

However, as it turns out, that goal is actually not possible to achieve, as the goal is to take their capital. Apparently, in EU you cannot demand a capital, unless it's their last province. I can demand the other province I have a claim on, but it will cost me diplomacy points.

Is it possible, through save game editing, console commands or otherwise, to change my war goal before I sue for peace?

Comment: In my current game I had the option to select the capital city hall suing for peace, but it deselected the other provinces when I did so saying, "You cannot take other provinces when demanding the capital. I was waging a lot of ways at the time and don't recall exactly. We're you not given the option to demand the capital at all?

Comment: That's weird. No, claiming the capital was simply not an option. I could vassalize or annex, but that required a warscore far greater than 100%.

Comment: Demanding the capital (without full annexation) is only an option when it is cut off from the rest of the country.

Comment: Thanks, @mmyers, for shedding some light on this mystery. :) It opens up for new tactics. I assume any province not connected by land, or more than one sea province away counts as "cut off"?

Comment: I don't remember the rules if the capital is isolated but is a port. The manual doesn't even mention that isolated capitals can be taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The save game file has an object, like this:

```
active_war=
{
  name="Venetian Conquest of Lombardia"
  history=
  {
    # Lots of battles and stuff
  }
  original_attacker="VEN"
  original_defender="MLO"
  # Now comes the interesting part
  {
    type="take_claim"
    province=104
    casus_belli="cb_conquest"
  }
```

So what I did was simply to change the province number from the original one to the one I wanted to claim. For the sake of history, you could also change the name of the war to something like "Thermonuclear War of the Spaghettis", but that's entirely optional.

I guess you can also change the war type. The file "00_wargoal_types.txt" has a lot of info on the different war types, how much they are worth in prestige, badboy points etc.